# Dynamically created divs aren't clickable

Tags: jquery

Can't dynamically create a div with a clickable class:

HTML:

```
<div id="line1">
    <div class='clickMe'>old clickable text</div>
</div>

<div id="line2">
    <div class='dontClickMe'>old unclickable text</div>
</div>

<div id='button'>button</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function() {
    alert("foo");
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#line2').html("<div class='clickMe'>new clickable text</div>");
});
```

Clicking the button replaces the code in line2.  It looks fine in debugging tools, i.e. Chrome dev elements.

But the "new clickable text" in line2 is not clickable.

Comment: you need to use live() instead of click() http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: responding to click event of element added to document after page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819915/jquery-responding-to-click-event-of-element-added-to-document-after-page-load)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `delegate` or `live`. Dynamically added `div`s wont have handlers bound unless you explicitly bind a new handler to them.

Answer (score 0):

Use .delegate()

```
var body = $("body");
body.delegate('.clickMe', 'click', function() {
    alert("foo");
});
```

Comment: Suggest revisiting this answer with `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`