# unsure about .on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using the `$.click()` method for triggering some events. But then I needed to set some events for some HTML elements before the elements were declared. Let's take this as an example:

```
<script>
    $('div.hide').click(function() {
        $('div.hide').css({'display' : 'none'});
     });
</script>
<div class="hide">some text</div>
```

The downside is that when setting the `.click()` method, the `div.hide` elements doesn't exist, so no trigger is set.

So I turned to the `.on()` method, like so:

```
<script>
    $('div.hide').on('click', function() {
        $('div.hide').css({'display' : 'none'});
    });
</script>
<div class="hide">some text</div>
```

But this also doesn't work. I thought calling `.on()` would make all existent and future `div.hide` elements trigger the `'click' function()`.

I managed to get past this inconvenience, but for my own knowledge I'd like to know what was I doing wrong. Is there no way to assign a trigger to future HTML elements?

My solituion was:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('div.hide').click(function() {
            $('div.hide').css({'display' : 'none'});
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="hide">some text</div>
```

Comment: Note about the `$(document).ready( function() { });` wrapper, that adds a event handler for the document ready event, so that the code within will not run until that event fires.  This ensures that the page is fully rendered before the script runs as opposed to when the javascript parses and runs during page render otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You missed the three-argument version:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div.hide', function() { ... });
```

That puts the handler on the `<body>` but it catches the events that bubble and invokes the handler when the target element matches the selector (the second argument).

The handler doesn't have to go on the `<body>`; it can be any parent container element of your `<div>`.

The "on" method replaces the older "live" and "delegate" methods, as well as "bind" itself.

Comment: Yet another reason that the hyper-overloading of `on` was a Bad Idea. I always use `delegate` for delegation and `on` (or one of its shortcuts) for non-delegation, for exactly this reason.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes I don't really understand what the point was.

Comment: I think the important point here is that it needs to attach the event somewhere, and the CLOSEST possible place in the DOM is the ideal/best place, so a DIV with an ID into which the non-existant elements are inserted would be best. +1 for that - as the OP appears to NOT understand that the attachement to the non-existant element still does NOT attach.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I really do consider this a bug in that it should, if it does not find an attachement, attach to the body which by definition always exists.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I agree, but without knowing what the DOM looks like and where those "hide" elements are being placed, it's hard to say precisely where to put the event handler. I agree that it's a good idea to put it as far down the DOM tree as possible. It'd be hard to make it attach the event handler to the body automatically; that would cause a lot of really bizarre behavior in many existing applications. It's not necessarily wrong for a jQuery object to be empty.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: *" I really do consider this a bug..."* Not following you...?

Comment: jQuery should attach to the body element, and as it does NOT, in the form that the OP has with the .on(), attach to anything and thus fails silently (an alternative is to attach to the document perhaps...) - note that the .on() correctly does work, if ONE element of that selector exists, but not if none exist at the point it attaches.

Comment: The library can't do that, because it cannot know for sure that that's what I expect.  I might be *conditionally* binding an event handler that I might not bind later under different conditions.

Comment: Actually, `on()` method is quite redundant alternative to `live()` since, using `on()`, we are forced to specify "dummy" base element (`body` for example). I personally am continuing using `live()` method since `on()` is not an equivalent alternative in its current form.

Comment: @MaratTanalin well ".live()" puts the handler on the `<body>` too - it's not really a "dummy" element; it's the point in the DOM at which bubbling events are to be intercepted. The problem with ".live()" is that it requires the DOM to be searched for the selector.

Comment: @Pointy I believe `live()` attaches handler to document or root element, not body, but this is implicit. On the contrary, using `on()`, we are forced to specify base element explicitly AND specify same selector as in `live()` too anyway, and `on()` requires the DOM to be searched for the selector at the same extent as `live()`.

Comment: No, ".on()" does not require that the DOM be searched for the match selector. On each event, the selector is applied only to the target element of the event.  The DOM must be searched, of course, for the handler element, but for example if creating a handler for clicks on `<td>` it's much more expensive with ".live()" than with ".on()".

Comment: @Pointy That's why `on()` could replace `delegate()`, but not `live()`. `live()` attaches event to document by nature (base element, of course, is searches once. I'm not talking about it) -- without need to redundantly specify element which handler is delegated to. For example, instead of `$('A.external').live('click', function() {});`, using `on()`, I'm forced to specify document explicitly: `$(document).on('click, 'A.external', 'function() {});`. That's unreasonably redundant.

Comment: @MaratTanalin yes yes, but what if there are 10,000 matches to "A.external"? `$("A.external").live(...)` will search the DOM and build the whole jQuery object for all those elements, even though it doesn't actually use it.

Comment: @Pointy No, `live()` will not search until event is occured. When event is occured, jQuery will just check that clicked element matches specified selector. You are probably confusing with `click()` method which does exactly what you've said and works only after DOM is ready.

Comment: @MaratTanalin sorry, but you are simply incorrect.  Test it yourself.  How can it **not** search the DOM?  The call to `$("A.external)` is completed **before** the call to the ".live()" method even starts. Surely the DOM is searched for `$("A.external").hide()`, right?  jQuery is not a "lazy evaluation" system.  That inefficiency is in fact the reason for the introduction of ".delegate()", [as it says in the jQuery documentation!](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for pointing that out. Still, `live()` is usually called before `BODY` element is even opened (otherwise, `delegate()` or `on()` is more appropriate), so it generally does not matter. `on()` could have less redundant syntax like `$.on()` making specifying base element optional and automatically using `document` in such cases.

Comment: I agree with that part, yes; and please understand that I am happy for you if you like using ".live()"; it rarely makes any difference, as you say.

Answer (score -2):

Use [jQuery.live method](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future

Comment: The ".on()" method, introduced with version 1.7, replaces the ".live()" method.  Indeed, ".live()" itself was really superseded by ".delegate()" some time ago.