# Attributes of images loaded with AJAX cannot be "seen" by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a user opens a page, I have a simple AJAX call that starts to load images in the background:

```
$('.image-container').load('/images/portfolio/');
```

This loads a duplicate of each image, a small one and a big one, for example:

```
<img src='...' class='small-image' data-picnum='0' style='height:100px; width:100px; opacity:1;'>
<img src='...' class='big-image' data-picnum='0' style='height:400px; width:400px; opacity:0;'>
```

When the small image is clicked, I use jQuery to retrieve its "data-picnum" attribute, then find the corresponding big image and make it visible:

```
var picNum = $(this).data('picnum');
$('.big-image[data-picnum="'+picNum+'"]').fadeIn();
```

However, jQuery fails to be able to read the "data-picnum" attribute when the image is loaded with AJAX. I have tested this with:

```
alert($(this).data('picnum');)
```

And the popup just says "undefined". I have also tried doing .live(), .on(), and .delegate as described in this post...
[Responding to click event of element added to document after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819915/responding-to-click-event-of-element-added-to-document-after-page-load) ... but none have worked for me. The images will load successfully

How can I get jQuery to "see" these new images' data attributes?

Comment: What's the context for using `$(this).data('picnum')`? At what point are you executing that code?

Comment: @Phil - the alert happens after the small image is clicked. That alert returns the correct 'data-picnum' value when the images are loaded normally, but when the images are loaded with AJAX it returns "undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using delegation but I'd say you're doing it incorrectly. Should look something like this...

```
$(document).on('click', '.small-image[data-picnum]', function(e) {
    var picNum = $(this).data('picnum');
    $('.big-image[data-picnum="' + picNum + '"]').fadeIn();
});
```

You can replace `document` above with any valid parent container that's not going to be dynamically inserted or replaced (via AJAX for example).

Comment: Also, `$('.image-container').load('/images/portfolio/');` has to return something useful. That looks like a folder name.

Comment: @PHPglue Don't know what that's got to do with this answer but I'd imagine it's loading the directory index (`index.html`, `index.php`, etc)

Comment: @PHPglue - It's loading the directory at www.mysite.com/images/portfolio. And what it returns is the <img> tags I showed above in my example.

Comment: @Phil - I haven't been able to get this to work yet - but just so I can understand better why do you put "[data-picnum]" in the first row of the code you suggested?

Comment: @jball037 Well, you only want to listen for clicks on `small-image` classed elements that have a `data-picnum` attribute. That's why I included both in the delegate selector

Comment: Okay, this ended up working - thanks for the help. The problem was actually that I was taking lines 2 and 3 of your code above and putting it into another function, and calling that function name on line 2. Any ideas on why this didn't work?

Comment: @jball037 Probably because `this` would not be correct in that context. You can use my code outside any other function. It will even work outside a document ready handler as the delegation works at the `document` level